# Using Ajax to insert data but it's taking time to insert

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

i'm using ajax to insert data into mysql but if i press the submit button it's taking more time to insert data hopefully someone here can do better than me please give a feedback.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type ="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

My Ajax Code:

```
<script>

        $(document).ready(function(){

            $("#button").click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var usId=$("#userId").val();
                var mailId=$("#mailId").val();
                var palId=$("#palId").val();
                var mtext=$("#umText").val();

                setInterval(function(){
                    $('#loadMesg').load("../validate/getMessage.php?mailId=<?php echo $_GET["mailId"]; ?>").fadeIn("slow");
                }, 200);

                $.ajax({
                    url:'../validate/updateMails.php',
                    method:'POST',
                    data:{
                        u_id:usId,
                        pal_id:palId,
                        u_mtext:mtext
                    },
                   success:function(data){
                       //alert(data);
                       $("#umText").val('');
                       $('#loadMesg').load("../validate/getMessage.php?mailId=<?php echo $_GET["mailId"]; ?>").fadeIn("slow");
                   }
                });

            });
        });



    </script>
```

And my Submit Form :

```
<form>
<input type="hidden" id="mailId" name="mailId" value="<?php echo $_GET["mailId"]; ?>">
<input type="hidden" id="palId" name="palId" value="<?php echo $_GET["palId"]; ?>">
<input type="hidden" id="userId" name="userId" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["u_id"]; ?>">
<textarea placeholder="Write M-Mail" id="umText" name="umText" class="input"></textarea>
<button type="submit" title="send" id="button"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i></button>
</form>
```

Comment: Why are you loading 4 different versions of jQuery? And define "more time" -- more than what?

Comment: it's enough to use latest one only?

Comment: @Jerad yes, latest and stable

Comment: As long as you don't have any code that explicitly requires an older version, then yes, latest one only.

Comment: which one is stable?

Comment: What is the setInterval for? This is loading the same content every 200 milliseconds.  You might want to change that

Comment: @Jerad check [this](https://code.jquery.com/) out

Comment: that one i'm using after insert it will fetch the data

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js
//link for JQuery latest version

Add only one JS:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```